# Configure MVC5 with angular4 routes

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to configure routes in MVC5, when i tried to refresh web-page 
withing angular 4 route it gives me

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
```

how can i config mvc routes to accept also angular routes:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Comment: Do you have proper controller class with proper action(with Route attribute) in it?

Comment: No i don't have

Comment: You need add a controller class and add appropriate action with route attributes on it in MVC 5 project then it will work

Comment: try my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601424/asp-net-mvc-with-angular-page-refresh-or-reload-gives-404-error/50601878#50601878

Comment: @JohnVelasquez your solution will prevent me from navigate to any of mvc5 views such as login\ register page. it will redirect me only to Home\Indx

Comment: @AnkurShah can you explain to me how attribute routing will solve my problem with angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

Add following rewrite rule to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: it doesn't wrok